# Maintaining Minimum amount of Microsoft Azure virtual machines instances with Auto Scale

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, autoscaling

I currently studying the Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines, with following.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-autoscale

However, I'm not sure I understanding the description correctly.
After I've set up the VMs with capacity minimum of 3 and max of 6, auto scale will balances the amounts of my VMs.

However, while I have the 3 instances and one of the instances got some kinds of error and shutdown? what will happen?

Does the Auto Scale will add the additional VM to maintain the minimum amounts or they does not add the VMs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, while I have the 3 instances and one of the instances got
>   some kinds of error and shutdown? what will happen?

It depends on your scaling rules. I test in my lab, my rule is: **scale out (Average) Percentage CPU >75, scale in (Average) Percentage CPU <25**. When I shutdown a VM inside the VM, Azure could check out the instance had been power off, but it does not scale out a new VM. The reason is that my instances do not meet scale out rules. When VM's percentage CPU>75, it will scale out a instance(it depends on your scaling rules).

More information about this please refer to this [link:How to use automatic scaling and Virtual Machine Scale Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview).

Comment: Thanks! While waiting for responses, I found the following article.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/service-healing-auto-recovery-of-virtual-machines/

It seems like it will attempt to reboot the instance if something happens. (Well I'm not sure this will cause infinite reboot process if instance holds the serious error)